# Idolatrous calendar names

Tags: avodah-zarah

In [Ezekiel](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.8.14) we find that tammuz is a god of heat.
My question being not how we can name our months after idolatrous Babylonian gods, but what is the difference between Babylonian and Roman gods? That is the for example the name January from the god janus.